# Fourier transform of equation $f_t + \nabla \cdot (gf)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to take the Fourier transform of this equation $f_t + \nabla \cdot (gf)=0$, because I want to know whether I can get kernel of this equation. Here we assume $\nabla \cdot g=0$. For example, we can use Fourier transform on heat equation $u_t - \Delta u =0$ to get $\hat u = e^{-|\xi|^2 t}u_{0}$.

So far, I can get $\hat f_t = \xi \hat{gf}(\xi)$ but don't know how to proceed to get $\hat f$.

We assume $g$ is a vector function in $\mathbb R^2$ and $f$ is a scalar function in $\mathbb R^2$.

Update: here I meant $f(x,t),g(x,t) \in \mathbb R^2 \times (0, \infty)$.

Comment: In your question they appear three functions, $f_t$, $f$ and $g$. you say $f(x,y) \in \mathbb R$ (calling x and y to the space coordinates), $g(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, but nothing about what is $f_t$. Finally, you want Fourier transform over $t$? over $(x,y)$?

Comment: When you say $u_t - \Delta u =0$ you mean $0 = u(t) - \nabla_t u(t) = u(t) - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(t) $ ?

Comment: Up to some annoying constants, $\mathcal{F}(g^j f)=\mathcal{F}(g^j)\ast\mathcal{F}(f)$.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui You are right. I just updated it.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui The laplacian operator is for the space, not the time $t$.